# Prove or disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem :**

Let $a_n$ is positive sequence satisfies  $\sum a_n < \infty$

Define $$b_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{kn}$$

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0$?

---

I think an answer is 'Yes' but I can't construct details.

This is my attempt :

Since $\sum a_n < \infty, \lim_{} a_n = 0$.

And, when $n$ goes large, sum has fewer terms, so $b_n$ is positive decreasing sequence so it converges definitely, but I can't sure it converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, you can show that
$$b_n \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k = \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\right|.$$